# Qualified class name for loading using custom class loader

Tags: java, classloader

I am Writing a custom class loader to load a class(Ex: Question.java),
if the Question.java class is in default package then I am able to get the input stream(`ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Test1.class")`)

but if the Question.java class is in different package(Ex: Exam), then `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Exam.Test1.class")` is returning null.

Please let me know if it's a problem with qualified name of class that i'm using or anything else.

Note: the custom class loader class is in default package.

Thanks!!

Comment: Would not the resource name for the class file of `Exam.Test1` be `Exam/Test1.class`?  With a slash?  Certainly if you were reading it from the standard class file layout in a jar or on a file system it would.

Comment: That works..thanks